# Why does SetFilePointerEx(1) succeed for an empty file that's open for reading only?

Tags: winapi

I do not understand why the following code, which sets the position of an open file handle relative to the base (i. e. sets the absolute position) succeeds when trying to set a positive position for an empty file that's open for reading only:

```
LARGE_INTEGER offset;
offset.QuadPart = 100;
LARGE_INTEGER pos = {0};
return ::SetFilePointerEx(_h, offset, &pos, FILE_BEGIN) != 0;
```

It returns a non-zero result, and the `pos` variable receives the value 100. That behavior is counter-intuitive for a GENRIC_READ file of size zero, what is the logic? I understand that this is normal behavior for files with write access.

P. S. The file is not overlapped and overall as simple as it can be with no fancy flags.

Does `SetFilePointerEx` ever fail at all for valid handles, positive absolute positions and plain files?

Comment: for what you need `SetFilePointerEx` ? this is not need api

Comment: @RbMm: what do you mean? What are the alternatives for `seek`ing a file (changing file position)?

Comment: i mean than no sense use this api. for what ? simply never use it

Comment: @RbMm: how do you read or write a file non-contiguously, then? I know `ReadFile` / `WriteFile` can accept the offset in the `lpOverlapped` argument, so I guess you could never use `SetFilePointerEx`, but then why shouldn't you?

Comment: `Note that it is not an error to set the file pointer to a position beyond the end of the file. `

Comment: of course by use file offset inside OVERLAPPED. for what need extra api call ?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: so you think that `SetFilePointerEx` always succeeds, and then if I tried to `SetEndOfFile` on a read-only file, only then it will fail?

Comment: I'm quoting the documentation there.

Comment: yes, SetFilePointerEx always succeeds in case file not open with FO_NO_INTERMEDIATE_BUFFERING, otherwise it must be sector size aligned

Comment: @RbMm: thanks for the explanation and for good advice. I'm working on a thin cross-platform I/O library that abstracts POSIX/Linux and WinAPI file access, and I need to provide `seek` for compatibility, but see yor point that `pread / pwrite`-style calls are always superior, and naked `seek` is not needed.

Comment: yes, in windows we never need use this call. it atavism. can give details answer

Comment: @RbMm, please do give it when you have the time.

Comment: The documentation says so.  It is a simple way to avoid a TOCTOU race, matters when reading a file that is actively being written to.

Comment: @RbMm *"in windows we never need use this call"* - Not sure about the *"we"* part here. Until I discover a better way to quickly shrink or grow a file, I'll just keep using `SetFilePointerEx` and `SetEndOfFile`.

Comment: @IInspectable *better way* - `SetFileInformationByHandle` with `FileEndOfFileInfo`

Comment: @RbMm Given how sparse the documentation on `SetFileInformationByHandle` is, I'll keep referring to `SetEndOfFile` as a better solution.

Comment: @IInspectable - if you look for `SetEndOfFile` implementation - the first this api call `ZwQueryInformationFile` with `FilePositionInformation` for get `CurrentByteOffset` which you set before by call `SetFilePointerEx` and then it call `ZwSetInformationFile` with this `CurrentByteOffset` and `FileEndOfFileInformation` and `FileAllocationInformation` ( last call is only optimization and optional) - so how you think - 2 additional api calls - `ZwSetInformationFile(FilePositionInformation)` + `ZwQueryInformationFile(FilePositionInformation)` make process faster or more reable or ?

Comment: @RbMm Raw performance isn't the only valid metric to optimize. Going to leave it at that, as I don't expect that that is something you'd be able to comprehend.

Comment: @IInspectable here not only this. why you think that do 2 api calls - `SetFilePointerEx` and `SetEndOfFile` - is better than one `SetFileInformationByHandle` ? (including error checking after `SetFilePointerEx`, already forget about TOCTOU )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SetFilePointerEx` internally call [`ZwSetInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-zwsetinformationfile) with *FilePositionInformation*. the [`FILE_POSITION_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_file_position_information) used as input.

exist only such restriction on this value

> If the file was opened or created with the
> `FILE_NO_INTERMEDIATE_BUFFERING` option, the value of `CurrentByteOffset`
> must be an integral multiple of the sector size of the underlying
> device.

also, always must be `0 <= CurrentByteOffset.QuadPart`- so position must be not negative.

no more restriction on position value. you can set it to any, not depend from file size. this call even never go to file system but handle by I/O manager.

all what he doing - set `CurrentByteOffset` in [`FILE_OBJECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_file_object)

how this is used ? when we call [`ZwReadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-zwreadfile) or [`ZwWriteFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-zwwritefile) - the optional parameter `ByteOffset` exist

> Pointer to a variable that specifies the starting byte offset in the
> file where the read operation will begin. If an attempt is made to
> read beyond the end of the file, ZwReadFile returns an error.
>
> If the call to ZwCreateFile set either of the CreateOptions flags
> FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_ALERT or FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT, the I/O
> Manager maintains the current file position. If so, the caller of
> ZwReadFile can specify that the current file position offset be used
> instead of an explicit ByteOffset value. This specification can be
> made by using one of the following methods:
>
> Specify a pointer to a LARGE_INTEGER value with the HighPart member
> set to -1 and the LowPart member set to the system-defined value
> FILE_USE_FILE_POINTER_POSITION.
>
> Pass a NULL pointer for ByteOffset.
>
> ZwReadFile updates the current file position by adding the number of
> bytes read when it completes the read operation, if it is using the
> current file position maintained by the I/O Manager.
>
> Even when the I/O Manager is maintaining the current file position,
> the caller can reset this position by passing an explicit ByteOffset
> value to ZwReadFile. Doing this automatically changes the current file
> position to that ByteOffset value, performs the read operation, and
> then updates the position according to the number of bytes actually
> read. This technique gives the caller atomic seek-and-read service.

so we can or explicit pass `ByteOffset` value or use additional api call for set it first in `FILE_OBJECT` and then I/O manager take it from here, if no explicit `ByteOffset` pointer.

note - in case asynchronous I/O - we need always explicit pass `ByteOffset` value or call just fail (exception for pipes and mailslot files)

in case `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` - `ByteOffset` taken from `OVERLAPPED` parameter. if it is 0 - the `ByteOffset` set to 0 pointer and `CurrentByteOffset` from `FILE_OBJECT` is used. and if pointer to `OVERLAPPED` not 0 - the exactly value from `OVERLAPPED` is explicit passed as `ByteOffset` value and `CurrentByteOffset` in `FILE_OBJECT` is ignored.

also always is ok use pointer to `OVERLAPPED` - not only for asynchronous file handles. simply for asynchronous - this is mandatory parameter and for synchronous is optional.

really faster and better - direct pass pointer to api call (read/write) than use separate api call, which take time, can (theoretical) fail, etc

use `SetFilePointer` may be exist sense only in legacu code, where it called from huge count of places, for not modify too many code

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you. You are a wealth of knowledge. The name of the `lpOverlapped` parameter did confuse me, I was certain it is only valid for files open for asynchronous operation, until someone told me otherwise just yesterday.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe - *I was certain it is only valid for files open for asynchronous operation* this is very common delusion. really `OVERLAPPED` is place for auxiliary parameters. - *Event*, *ApcContext*, *IoStatusBlock* and *ByteOffset*.